# Android expandable listview always scrolls down to bottom

Tags: android, expandablelistview

My `ExpandableListView` always scrolls down to bottom.
How can I stop this behaviour?
I had used `android:transcriptMode="disabled"`

but it did not work.

Comment: post the activity and layout file..